# Ionic 3 refrescar el menu izquierdo despues de loguearse

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic-framework, ionic3

Necesito mostrar elementos del menú lateral según el rol del usuario. entonces miro en app.html si la página muestra los items correspondientes al rol. pero no muestra elementos en el menú lateral justo después de iniciar sesión, pero después de actualizar la aplicación con el botón Refesh del navegador muestra los elementos correctos como debería. Supongo que el problema es Ionic:  ¿Cómo puedo actualizar la aplicación para que aparezcan nuevos elementos de menú?

Cada vez que inicio sesión con otro usuario / rol, muestra el menú de acuerdo con el usuario / rol anterior.

**app.component.ts**

```
if (this.userData.roles["0"]["name"] == "bikeuser") {
        this.pages = [
          { title: "Mi perfil", icon: 'contact', component: ProfilePage },
          { title: "Solicitar", icon: 'bicycle', component: RequestAngelPage },
          { title: "Seguimiento", icon: 'photos', component: TrackingCardPage },
          { title: "Terminados", icon: 'close-circle', component: RequestFinishBikeuserPage }
        ];


else if (this.userData.roles["0"]["name"] == "Biciangel") {
        this.pages = [

          { title: "Mi perfil", icon: 'contact', component: ProfilePage },
          { title: "Sin asignar", icon: 'body', component: UnassignedRequestsPage },
          { title: "Asignadas", icon: 'people', component: RequestsPage },
          { title: "Terminados", icon: 'close-circle', component: RequestFinishedPage }
        ];
      }
```

**app.html**

```
 <button ion-item detail-none *ngFor="let page of pages" (click)="openPage(page)">
        <ion-icon *ngIf="page.icon" name="{{page.icon}}" item-left></ion-icon>
        {{page.title}}
      </button>
```

Es decir si inicio sesion no muestra Mi perfil. Pero al darle actualizar al navegador si muestra el item mi perfil y los demas items. Por favor una explicacion acorde a lo que acabe de colocar porque he buscado en internet y no encuentro algo sobre esto

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar el modulo [Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/).

Ejemplo (simplificado), explicación en los comentarios:

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

// Con publish asignas el valor, ej. si el usuario ha iniciado o no
constructor( public events: Events ) {}

is_logged_user( val ) {

  this.events.publish('usuario:iniciado', val );
}


// Y luego puedes comprobar el valor con subscribe
// en la página que deseas 

public is_logged: boolean;    

constructor( public events: Events ) {

  this.is_logged = false;

  events.subscribe('usuario:iniciado', val => {

      this.is_logged = val;        
  });
}
```

Después puedes comprobar si el usuario ha iniciado sesión o no con la variable `is_logged` y muestras el contenido según valor:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="is_logged">
   // Muestra contenido si el usuario ha iniciado sesión
</ng-container>
```